# fastlane existing file at resultBundlePath

Tags: fastlane

When I run my fast lane build it fails with

`xcodebuild: error: Existing file at -resultBundlePath "/Users/dude/workspace/testMe/output/testMe.result"`

My lane actions are

- setup_jenkins
- clean_build_artifacts
- increment_build_number
- match
- gym
- pilot
- reset_git_repo

I know I can just add an action to delete this file specifically, but it seems more likely that I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem until I browsed fastlane code and found a workaround. Setting `result_bundle` to `false` helped in my case, e.g.

```
desc "Submit a new build to App Store"
lane :production do
    setup_jenkins(result_bundle: false)
    gym(...)
    deliver(...)
end
```